# Do fragments which container is removed continue to exist?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets say i have some `View` which then I add a `Fragment` to:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
           add(R.id.container, new SomeFragment());
```

Then I remove that view from view hierarchy, allowing it to be collected:

```
removeView(root.findViewById(R.id.container));
```

Is `SomeFragment` removed too? Can it be collected? Or is `FragmentManager` still holding reference to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, `FragmentManager` maintains a list of `Fragment` references that have been added. Just removing the container view from hierarchy does not make the fragment object garbage collectible.

To remove a fragment from display, invoke its appropriate lifecycle methods and eventually make it collectible, use a `remove` or `replace` fragment transaction.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow call `remove` automatically when view is removed from hierarchy (is there an event or some method in `View` class)?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the view youself from hierarchy?